# Natively controlling Dell external monitor brightness in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-display

I read online that the Windows 10 has a native brightness control slider in the [action center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-screen-brightness-in-windows-3f67a2f2-5c65-ceca-778b-5858fc007041#Category=Windows_10). However, this slider is not available to me as I use an external monitor (Dell 32" 4K monitor a.k.a U3219Q) plugged directly to my GPU over DisplayPort.

Installing Dell's own Display Manager software seems to be the only way of controlling the monitor brightness dynamically (screenshow below), which makes me think that there's a way to control this, so is there a way to natively do this with Windows 10/11 action center or a shortcut key?

Launching the Dell Display Manager app 10 times a day sounds silly. There's surely probably a better way I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found open source Twinkle Tray which aces at this. Works for probably most monitor brands and has the ability to assign shortcuts. https://twinkletray.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find a program to control brightness natively via action center or shortcut keys (it seems Windows 11 might not support it), but Dell Display Manager (DDM) 2.0 has a system tray pop-up icon, so clicking on that pop-up will similarily show your monitor controls for brightness. You can also use the open-source software, [Monitarian](https://github.com/emoacht/Monitorian), for the same effect. This method is pretty similar to using action center, and will save you from needing to open the DDM program every time.

[Screenshot of system tray controls from Dell Display Manager 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngXH6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).